# The Facebook (a double connect wall)

Tags: knowledge, visual, connect-wall, movies

This is a double connect wall puzzle.  The objective is to rearrange the sixteen people below in the 4x4 grid such that each row of 4 will be related by a common theme and each column of 4 will also be related a common theme.  In total, there will be 8 different themes/categories.

After discovering the 8 themes, attempt to determine the intended title for the puzzle, which is three words: `F____ ___ _____s`

[image: 1]

Since several of these people might be unfamiliar, rather than force everyone to paste thumbnails into a reverse image search, I've added a clue for each image.  Each clue is a movie title unless otherwise noted, and the ordering is in reading order (left to right, top to bottom).

1. The Producers (1967)
2. Austin Powers: International Man of Mystery
3. Jerry Maguire
4. Bohemian Rhapsody
5. The Bodyguard
6. Any Given Sunday
7. Wimbledon
8. Training Day
9. Space Jam
10. Joker
11. Raiders of the Lost Ark
12. Song: Low
13. All That Jazz
14. Jupiter Ascending
15. Song: How You Remind Me
16. TV Show: Ginny and Georgia

Comment: I've identified 13 out of 16 faces; do you mind if I create a community wiki answer that provides quick access in a spoiler tag (to include wiki links) for those who don't want to have to search for it?

Comment: @TacoタコスI don't mind if you create a spoiler protected community wiki answer.  I tried to make it easier by providing the clues but some might still be a little difficult to pinpoint.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks in part to the community wiki answer, the people in question are:

> Kenneth Mars, Austin Powers, Cuba Gooding Jr., Freddie Mercury

> Whitney Houston, Joe Montana, Venus Williams, Denzel Washington

> Michael Jordan, Joaquin Phoenix, Indiana Jones, Flo Rida

> John Stockton, Jupiter Jones, Chad Kroeger, Georgia Miller

Note that

> some of these people are the characters rather than the actors portraying them.

From here, we can fairly easily group them into four categories. From smallest to largest:

> U.S. Cities: AUSTIN Powers, Whitney HOUSTON, Joaquin PHOENIX, John STOCKTON

> U.S. States: Joe MONTANA, Denzel WASHINGTON, INDIANA Jones, FLO RIDA

> Countries: CUBA Gooding Jr., Michael JORDAN, CHAD Kroeger, GEORGIA Miller

> Planets: Kenneth MARS, Freddie MERCURY, VENUS Williams, JUPITER Jones

We can also categorize them based on who they are:

> Actors: Joaquin Phoenix, Denzel Washington, Cuba Gooding Jr., Kenneth Mars

> Athletes: John Stockton, Joe Montana, Michael Jordan, Venus Williams

> Characters: Austin Powers, Indiana Jones, Georgia Miller, Jupiter Jones

> Musicians: Whitney Houston, Flo Rida, Chad Kroeger, Freddie Mercury

Conveniently, each category in the first group contains exactly one member of each category in the second group, allowing us to create the following connect wall:

> [image: table with above names and categories]

Given the presentation and the fact that the first four categories I found are all types of

> place, I'd guess that the title is "Faces and Places" or something similar.

Comment: Oof, you just pipped me by 12 whole seconds! Way to go, nicely done :) +1

Comment: Nice way to solve your first puzzle here!  Congratulations!  BTW the intended title is what you answered.

Answer (score 10):

The double connecting wall can be resolved as follows:

> [image: Resolved double wall]
>
>  Here, the pictured people (four of which require the names of their depicted *characters* for this to work) can be divided first by occupation (ACTOR, CHARACTER, SPORTS STAR or MUSICIAN) and then secondly by sharing a connection within their names - i.e. whether it contains the name of a PLANET, a COUNTRY, a US STATE, or a US CITY.

As for the intended title, I would suggest something along the lines of:

> **FACES FROM PLACES**

Comment: (Since I was pipped to the post by @juicifer I shall leave my post as it was at the time I posted it without making any additional modifications, but my reasoning for the choice of title was that rot13(SNPRF naq CYNPRF eulzr fngvfslvatyl, nf jryy nf ersyrpgvat gur gjb 'glcrf bs pbaarpgvba' urer - gur crbcyr gurzfryirf naq gur trbtencuvp ybpngvbaf va gurve anzrf. Sbe jung vg'f jbegu V cersre gurve 'Snprf NAQ Cynprf' bire zl 'Snprf SEBZ Cynprf', nf guvf nccrnef gb zngpu gur punenpgre pbhag va gur chmmyr'f oynaxf, juvpu V unq abg gnxra vagb nppbhag...))

Comment: I've also just noticed one very amusing typo in the image that slipped past my quality control - I'll let you spot it yourselves! :D

Comment: lol *sheds a tear*

Comment: What are the odds that after being up for 10+ hours, the first two answers arrive less than 30 seconds apart?  Actually I think what happened is that this question got pushed off the front page by a lot of other edited questions and only got bumped back up by the community answer.  I was expecting it to be solved pretty quickly.

Comment: yeah, the community answer definitely helped me. I will say that I would've gotten to my answer a lot quicker had I realized that rot13(trbetvn vf n pbhagel nf jryy nf n fgngr). pretty embarrassing lmao

Comment: It was only while updating the community answer with the missing individuals that it dawned on me what the 'trick' to 4 of the faces entailed. Then it dawned on me what I'd been missing, as I had the more 'wordplay'-based groups relatively well-formed, but was missing the more 'obvious' side of things! :)

Comment: @juicifer rot13(V qvq Trbetvn ba checbfr. Ng bar cbvag, V unq Vfenry Xnznxnjvjb'byr vafgrnq bs Punq Xebrtre naq Punq Qnasbegu (Uvtu Fpubby Zhfvpny) vafgrnq bs Trbetvn Zvyyre.  Ohg Vfenry jnf n yvggyr gbb fgenvtugsbejneq fb V fjvgpurq vg. Fnzr jvgu Qnyynf Xrhpury (onfronyy cynlre).  V nyfb qvqa'g trg gb hfr fbzr tbbq cbffvovyvgvrf yvxr Unaanu Zbagnan, Irebavpn Znef, naq Oehab Znef orpnhfr bs qhcyvpngvba.)

Answer (score 4):

***Note** This answer doesn't solve the puzzle, but rather offers a quick way to identify the faces in the puzzle's grid through links to Wikipedia articles surrounding the people the faces belong to.*

---

###### Row 1

> [Kenneth Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Mars), [Mike Myers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Myers), [Cuba Gooding Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuba_Gooding_Jr.), and [Freddie Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddie_Mercury)

###### Row 2

> [Whitney Houston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_Houston), [Joe Montana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Montana), [Venus Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Williams), and [Denzel Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denzel_Washington)

###### Row 3

> [Michael Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan), [Joaquin Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joaquin_Phoenix), [Harrison Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrison_Ford), and [Flo Rida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flo_Rida)

###### Row 4

> [John Stockton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stockton), [Mila Kunis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mila_Kunis), [Chad Kroeger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chad_Kroeger), and [Brianne Howey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianne_Howey)